# Flutter onAuthStateChanged not working on web

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-web

I am trying to migrate a flutter app into web.
This piece of code works on app.

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged.listen((firebaseUser) {
  setState(() {
      user = firebaseUser;
  });
});
```

However when I `flutter run -d chrome`. Run it on webview, there is an error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following JSNoSuchMethodError was thrown building Builder:
NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: 'onAuthStateChanged'

The relevant error-causing widget was:
MaterialApp org-dartlang-app:///packages/app/home_app.dart:66:16
```

I am currently using `firebase_auth: 0.15.3+1` and configured using this 
[firebase_auth_web tutorial](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth_web/README.md)

I wonder if there is any problem with the `onAuthStateChange` itself?